# Notation: $\sum_i \dfrac{\partial A_i}{\partial x_i} \boldsymbol{e}_i$ using $\nabla$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation

I would like to write $\sum_i \dfrac{\partial A_i}{\partial x_i} \boldsymbol{e}_i$ using the $\nabla$ operator if possible, where $\boldsymbol{A}=A_1\boldsymbol{e}_1 + A_2\boldsymbol{e}_2 + A_3\boldsymbol{e}_3$. is a vector. Grad nor divergence give this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are $e_i$?

Comment: @AhmedHussein the standard basis for the 3d euclidean space

Comment: Well, ${\bf A}\cdot {\bf e}_i = A_i$, then $\nabla({\bf A}\cdot {\bf e}_i)$ is the gradient of $A_i$, and finally $\nabla({\bf A}\cdot {\bf e}_i) \cdot {\bf e}_i = \frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x_i}$. Is that ok? Or shouldn't we use ${\bf e}_i$?

Comment: @IvoTerek can you post it as an answer so that the question does not remain unanswered? or do you recommend to delete the quesiton?

Comment: I'll convert it to an answer, don't worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write ${\bf A}\cdot {\bf e}_i = A_i$, so $\nabla({\bf A}\cdot {\bf e}_i)$ is the gradient of $A_i$, To pick the $i-$th component, we dot that with ${\bf e}_i$ again to obtain $\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x_i} = \nabla({\bf A}\cdot {\bf e}_i)\cdot {\bf e}_i$, and the desired field is: $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x_i}\,{\bf e}_i = \sum_{i=1}^n (\nabla({\bf A}\cdot {\bf e}_i)\cdot {\bf e}_i)\,{\bf e}_i.$$